# MediaWiki hook to refresh script on article load

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have a PHP scripts which displays lists of employees on my MediaWiki. I also have a special page, where you can administrate which users are employees, that works very well. However when you make a backend change on the special page, the change isn't displayed on the wikipage, where it's inserted with a tag, until after you edit that page, and change nothing, and save it.

It can only be because I'm using the wrong hook. I'm trying to use this hook instead, but it doesn't seem to be working: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ArticlePageDataBefore

Right now I'm using this hook. Just changing the variable name doesn't work:

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'wfEmployeesParserInit';

// Hook our callback function into the parser
function wfEmployeesParserInit( Parser $parser ) {
  // When the parser sees the <sample> tag, it executes 
  // the wfEmployeesRender function (see below)
  $parser->setHook( 'employees', 'wfEmployeesRender' );
        // Always return true from this function. The return value does not denote
        // success or otherwise have meaning - it just must always be true.
  return true;
}

// Execute 
function wfEmployeesRender( $input, array $args, Parser $parser, PPFrame $frame ) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. I found a solution.

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'wfNewsParserInit';

function wfNewsRender($input, array $args, Parser $parser, PPFrame $frame)
{
  $parser->disableCache();
  ...
```

Comment: Note that this is probably not the *optimal* solution, even if it may be sufficient for your needs. The problem with this method is that it forces any pages using your extension to be reparsed every time they're viewed, even if the displayed data hasn't changed. If the data changes only infrequently (e.g. by manual editing via a special page), it would be better to store a list of pages using the extension, and have the process that updates the data purge those pages from the parser cache.

Comment: You are right, it might not be the best solution. However this project is limited to max 50 users and 3-4 at the same time, so that wasn't an issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The hook isn't to blame here; rather it is MediaWiki's page caching -- pages are not updated unless they are edited or a periodic cache purge occurs. There are a few ways around this issue; you can do null edits; you can turn off caching; or you can purge the contents of the affected page(s), which force MW to re-render the page.

Some useful links with details of these methods:

[Mediawiki API: Purge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Purge)

[How do I disable caching for pages using my extension?](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extensions_FAQ#How_do_I_disable_caching_for_pages_using_my_extension.3F)

[MW Manual: Purge](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Purge)

[How to prevent MW from caching pages](https://www.cookipedia.co.uk/recipes_wiki/How_to_prevent_MediaWiki_caching_pages)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't read you links yet, but maybe you can answer this before though. I want it to update once you make changes to my special page script. Can I force recache from there? Then that would solve it :) And thanks, I've been struggling with this for days